# How to change FCM endpoint in firebase-admin sdk

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

Within firebase-admin sdk, the URL endpoints for FCM are hard coded. But my requirement is to change the endpoint because of hosting environment issue.

Is there a way by which I can configure the FCM URL used by firebase-admin-sdk?

Comment: Is your environment behind a proxy? Is that the problem?

Comment: Sort of. There is dedicated system which handles the communication back and forth. Which means any request to my server comes through this system and any request to third party system goes via this system. My server communicates with this system only.

Comment: There's an on going effort to support specifying HTTP proxy settings for the Admin SDK. Other means of changing endpoint URLs are not planned at the moment.

Comment: Thank you @HiranyaJayathilaka, is it advisible to modify the firebase-admin-sdk code base to make it suitable of this need?

Comment: I recommend first trying to get this done via Node.js `http.Agent` API. We are adding support for it in the Admin SDK as we speak: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/pull/402

Comment: @HiranyaJayathilaka Is this feature added in firebase-admin SDK for Java? I need to pass the traffic through a middleware server. If not added, should I recompile the admin sdk with changed endpoint urls?

Comment: Java SDK has supported proxy configurations for a long time. You ca either set the standard env variables or use the `HttpTransport` API. https://medium.com/faun/firebase-accessing-firestore-and-firebase-through-a-proxy-server-c6c6029cddb1